# Find the Value of a Nested Struct for a JSON file

Tags: json, go

I have managed to create the Structs required to parse the JSON file which can be seen below:
I'm looking to pull out the value for Site Visited "protocol and site_domain" like below.

"protocol": "ipv4",
"site_domain": [
"8.8.9.9",
"1.1.1.1",
"67.31.88.31:443"

Which is buried deep in the struct but i don't know how to pull the value after reading the JSON file via my script. Does anyone have an idea on how i may achieve this ? I was thinking something like

```
fmt.Println(+report.SiteVisited.Protocol.Site_domain)
```

But I'm having no luck

```
{
  "upload": 14234234,
  "unit_num": 154353,
  "processed": 1598558692,
  "super_report": [
    {
      "info": {
        "file": {
          "file_type": "Binary",
          "file_name": "url_list_new.zip",
          "file_path": "/home/user5",
          "size": 6654,
          "hashes": [
            {
              "name": "md5",
              "value": "fsfdsfwerfsdfsf4566f"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha1",
              "value": "8989424232gfsdfsfsdfsd"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha256",
              "value": "727206bf5c786a82ddf0bc146afff395ed2ec9sdf"
            }
          ]
        },
        "identification": {
          "success": true,
          "name": "ZIP",
          "version": "Gen5",
          "author": "EnigmaTesters"
        }
      },
      "qualification": {
        "final": false,
        "qualification": 0,
        "factor": 0,
        "scan_results": [
          {
            "type": "internal",
            "qualification": 0,
            "factor": 0,
            "name": "Azure Repo Sensor 6",
            "version": "2.7.9.3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "behavior": [
        {
          "priority": 3,
          "section": 14,
          "description": "Crashes"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "info": {
        "file": {
          "file_type": "PE",
          "file_name": "house.txt",
          "file_path": "/home/user5/",
          "size": 8862,
          "properties": {
            "attributes": 0,
            "modified_time": 1593481746,
            "access_time": 0,
            "creation_time": 0
          },
          "entropy": 7.8,
          "hashes": [
            {
              "name": "md5",
              "value": "sdfsdfssdfsdfsfsfsdfsdvxcvxvcv"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha1",
              "value": "xxxfsdfwr234234213sfsfsdfsfsd"
            },
            {
              "name": "sha256",
              "value": "xzfrwerwerwerfdsa890876543234234ssdfxcvsdfsdf"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "qualification": {
        "final": false,
        "qualification": 0,
        "factor": 0,
        "scan_results": [
          {
            "type": "internal",
            "qualification": 0,
            "factor": 0,
            "name": "Azure Sentinel",
            "version": "2.7.9.3"
          }
        ]
      },
      "behavior": [
        {
          "priority": 5,
          "protocol": 12,
          "description": "Uses /tmp folder"
        },
        {
          "priority": 5,
          "protocol": 0,
          "description": "5 dirs"
        },
        {
          "priority": 5,
          "protocol": 0,
          "description": "Creates dir"
        },
        {
          "priority": 5,
          "protocol": 10,
          "description": "updates struct"
        },
        {
          "priority": 5,
          "protocol": 12,
          "description": "Locates home"
        },
        {
          "priority": 4,
          "protocol": 22,
          "description": "Created a text file."
        },
        {
          "priority": 3,
          "protocol": 0,
          "description": "Too many stars in text file "
        }
      ],
      "sites_visted": [
        {
          "protocol": "https",
          "site_domain": [
            "bonn.sh",
            "conn.sh",
            "t00ls.ru",
            "cdr.eu"
          ]
        },
        {
          "protocol": "https",
          "site_domain": [
            "http://bin.com/jRersdf1u",
            "htto://bin.com/pxcsdfssYZ"
          ]
        },
        {
          "protocol": "ipv4",
          "site_domain": [
            "8.8.9.9",
            "1.1.1.1",
            "67.31.88.31:443"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My Go Script is below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type MainReport struct {
    Upload      int `json:"upload"`
    UnitNum     int `json:"unit_num"`
    Processed   int `json:"processed"`
    SuperReport []struct {
        Info struct {
            File struct {
                FileType    string `json:"file_type"`
                FileName    string `json:"file_name"`
                FilePath    string `json:"file_path"`
                Size        int    `json:"size"`
                Hashes      []struct {
                    Name  string `json:"name"`
                    Value string `json:"value"`
                } `json:"hashes"`
            } `json:"file"`
            Identification struct {
                Success bool   `json:"success"`
                Name    string `json:"name"`
                Version string `json:"version"`
                Author  string `json:"author"`
            } `json:"identification"`
        } `json:"info,omitempty"`
        Qualification struct {
            Final         bool `json:"final"`
            Qualification int  `json:"qualification"`
            Factor        int  `json:"factor"`
            ScanResults   []struct {
                Type          string `json:"type"`
                Qualification int    `json:"qualification"`
                Factor        int    `json:"factor"`
                Name          string `json:"name"`
                Version       string `json:"version"`
            } `json:"scan_results"`
        } `json:"qualification"`
        Behavior []struct {
            Priority    int    `json:"priority"`
            Section     int    `json:"section"`
            Description string `json:"description"`
        } `json:"behavior"`
        Info2 struct {
            File struct {
                FileType    string `json:"file_type"`
                FileSubtype string `json:"file_subtype"`
                FileName    string `json:"file_name"`
                FilePath    string `json:"file_path"`
                Size        int    `json:"size"`
                Properties  struct {
                    Attributes   int `json:"attributes"`
                    ModifiedTime int `json:"modified_time"`
                    AccessTime   int `json:"access_time"`
                    CreationTime int `json:"creation_time"`
                } `json:"properties"`
                Entropy float64 `json:"entropy"`
                Hashes  []struct {
                    Name  string `json:"name"`
                    Value string `json:"value"`
                } `json:"hashes"`
            } `json:"file"`
        } `json:"info,omitempty"`
        SitesVisted []struct {
            Protocol   string   `json:"protocol"`
            SiteDomain []string `json:"site_domain"`
        } `json:"sites_visted,omitempty"`
    } `json:"super_report"`
}

// main fuction is below
func main() {

    jsonFile, err := os.Open("file.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened json file")
    defer jsonFile.Close()

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened file.json")

    byteEmpValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

    var report MainReport

    json.Unmarshal(byteEmpValue, &report)

    fmt.Println(+report.Processed)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", report)
}
```

Comment: SuperReport, SitesVisited, and SiteDomain are all slices of structs, to access an element of a slice you need to index into the slice, or you can loop/range over the slice to visit each element. [slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), [for range](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range).

Comment: Run `go vet` on the program and fix the reported error (Info and Info2 have the same JSON field name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only an example, could you please show an example of the result that you want?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type myStruct struct {
    Upload      int `json:"upload"`
    UnitNum     int `json:"unit_num"`
    Processed   int `json:"processed"`
    SuperReport []struct {
        Info struct {
            File struct {
                FileType string `json:"file_type"`
                FileName string `json:"file_name"`
                FilePath string `json:"file_path"`
                Size     int    `json:"size"`
                Hashes   []struct {
                    Name  string `json:"name"`
                    Value string `json:"value"`
                } `json:"hashes"`
            } `json:"file"`
            Identification struct {
                Success bool   `json:"success"`
                Name    string `json:"name"`
                Version string `json:"version"`
                Author  string `json:"author"`
            } `json:"identification"`
        } `json:"info,omitempty"`
        Qualification struct {
            Final         bool `json:"final"`
            Qualification int  `json:"qualification"`
            Factor        int  `json:"factor"`
            ScanResults   []struct {
                Type          string `json:"type"`
                Qualification int    `json:"qualification"`
                Factor        int    `json:"factor"`
                Name          string `json:"name"`
                Version       string `json:"version"`
            } `json:"scan_results"`
        } `json:"qualification"`
        Behavior []struct {
            Priority    int    `json:"priority"`
            Section     int    `json:"section"`
            Description string `json:"description"`
        } `json:"behavior"`
        Info2 struct {
            File struct {
                FileType   string `json:"file_type"`
                FileName   string `json:"file_name"`
                FilePath   string `json:"file_path"`
                Size       int    `json:"size"`
                Properties struct {
                    Attributes   int `json:"attributes"`
                    ModifiedTime int `json:"modified_time"`
                    AccessTime   int `json:"access_time"`
                    CreationTime int `json:"creation_time"`
                } `json:"properties"`
                Entropy float64 `json:"entropy"`
                Hashes  []struct {
                    Name  string `json:"name"`
                    Value string `json:"value"`
                } `json:"hashes"`
            } `json:"file"`
        } `json:"info2,omitempty"`
        SitesVisted []struct {
            Protocol   string   `json:"protocol"`
            SiteDomain []string `json:"site_domain"`
        } `json:"sites_visted,omitempty"`
    } `json:"super_report"`
}

func main() {
    a := `{"upload":14234234,"unit_num":154353,"processed":1598558692,"super_report":[{"info":{"file":{"file_type":"Binary","file_name":"url_list_new.zip","file_path":"/home/user5","size":6654,"hashes":[{"name":"md5","value":"fsfdsfwerfsdfsf4566f"},{"name":"sha1","value":"8989424232gfsdfsfsdfsd"},{"name":"sha256","value":"727206bf5c786a82ddf0bc146afff395ed2ec9sdf"}]},"identification":{"success":true,"name":"ZIP","version":"Gen5","author":"EnigmaTesters"}},"qualification":{"final":false,"qualification":0,"factor":0,"scan_results":[{"type":"internal","qualification":0,"factor":0,"name":"Azure Repo Sensor 6","version":"2.7.9.3"}]},"behavior":[{"priority":3,"section":14,"description":"Crashes"}]},{"info":{"file":{"file_type":"PE","file_name":"house.txt","file_path":"/home/user5/","size":8862,"properties":{"attributes":0,"modified_time":1593481746,"access_time":0,"creation_time":0},"entropy":7.8,"hashes":[{"name":"md5","value":"sdfsdfssdfsdfsfsfsdfsdvxcvxvcv"},{"name":"sha1","value":"xxxfsdfwr234234213sfsfsdfsfsd"},{"name":"sha256","value":"xzfrwerwerwerfdsa890876543234234ssdfxcvsdfsdf"}]}},"qualification":{"final":false,"qualification":0,"factor":0,"scan_results":[{"type":"internal","qualification":0,"factor":0,"name":"Azure Sentinel","version":"2.7.9.3"}]},"behavior":[{"priority":5,"protocol":12,"description":"Uses /tmp folder"},{"priority":5,"protocol":0,"description":"5 dirs"},{"priority":5,"protocol":0,"description":"Creates dir"},{"priority":5,"protocol":10,"description":"updates struct"},{"priority":5,"protocol":12,"description":"Locates home"},{"priority":4,"protocol":22,"description":"Created a text file."},{"priority":3,"protocol":0,"description":"Too many stars in text file "}],"sites_visted":[{"protocol":"https","site_domain":["bonn.sh","conn.sh","t00ls.ru","cdr.eu"]},{"protocol":"https","site_domain":["http://bin.com/jRersdf1u","htto://bin.com/pxcsdfssYZ"]},{"protocol":"ipv4","site_domain":["8.8.9.9","1.1.1.1","67.31.88.31:443"]}]}]}`

    var myStruct myStruct
    var address []string

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), &myStruct); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, report := range myStruct.SuperReport {
        for _, k := range report.SitesVisted {
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", k)
            address = append(address, k.SiteDomain...)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(address)
}
```

Output:

```
{Protocol:https SiteDomain:[bonn.sh conn.sh t00ls.ru cdr.eu]}
{Protocol:https SiteDomain:[http://bin.com/jRersdf1u htto://bin.com/pxcsdfssYZ]}
{Protocol:ipv4 SiteDomain:[8.8.9.9 1.1.1.1 67.31.88.31:443]}
[bonn.sh conn.sh t00ls.ru cdr.eu http://bin.com/jRersdf1u htto://bin.com/pxcsdfssYZ 8.8.9.9 1.1.1.1 67.31.88.31:443]
```

Comment: Wow this is great, what if i was looking to get the following in a list

Comment: Wow this is great, what if i was looking to get the following in a list "bonn.sh, conn.sh, t00ls.ru, cdr.su, http://bin.com/jRersdf1u htto://bin.com/pxcsdfssYZ, 8.8.9.9, 1.1.1.1, 67.31.88.31:443"

Comment: I tried to change the bottom of the code to this and it did not work " for _, report := range myStruct.SuperReport.SitesVisted {
  for _, k := range report.Protocol {
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", k)
  }
 }"

Comment: Edited with the solution

Comment: Thanks so much ! This is extremely helpful !